# How can I select element of a list containing (a,b) where both a and b ara rational numbers and not integers?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a list of equations and I solve them

```
list = {x^2 - 2 x - 3 == 0, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1 == 0, x^2 - 2 == 0, 
   6 x^2 - 5 x + 1 == 0};
mytab = Table[Solve[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

> {{{x -> -1}, {x ->
> 3}}, {{x -> -1}, {x -> -(1/2)}}, {{x -> -Sqrt[2]}, {x -> Sqrt[
> 2]}}, {{x -> 1/3}, {x -> 1/2}}}

I would like to select the element `{{x -> 1/3}, {x -> 1/2}}`, because `1/3, 1/2` are rational numbers and not integer numbers. How can I select them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility out of many

```
list={x^2 - 2  x - 3 == 0, 2  x^2 + 3  x + 1 == 0, x^2 - 2==0, 6 x^2 - 5  x + 1== 0};   
Cases[Solve /@ list, {{x -> _Rational}, {x -> _Rational}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: You do not need to type

```
mytab = Table[Solve[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

You can just type `Solve /@ list` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
Cases[{{_ -> _Rational} ..}] @ mytab
```

> ```
> {{{x -> 1/3}, {x -> 1/2}}}
> ```

```
Select[FreeQ[_Integer]] @ mytab
```

> ```
> {{{x -> 1/3}, {x -> 1/2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
l = {x^2 - 2 x - 3 == 0, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1 == 0, x^2 - 2 == 0, 6 x^2 - 5 x + 1 == 0};
```

Using `Map` instead of `Table`:

```
Last@(Solve[# && NotElement[x, Integers], x, Rationals] & /@ l)

(*{{x -> 1/3}, {x -> 1/2}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[mytab, AllTrue[MatchQ[_Rational]]@*Values@*Flatten]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Pick[mytab,mytab[[All,All,1,2]]/.{{_Rational,_Rational}->True,
  {_,_}->False}]//Catenate

(* {{x->1/3},{x->1/2}} *)
```

(To be pedantic, the OP is asking that both values have the `Head` 'Rational')

```
{Element[#,Rationals],Element[#,Rationals]}&/@mytab[[All,All,1,2]]

(* {{True,True},{True,True},{False,False},{True,True}}  *)
```